# Notation - continuity limit under an integral

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, notation

I'm currently showing that the following integral is continuous:

$$\int_{g_1(x)}^{g_2(x)} f(x,y) dy$$

Where $g_1, g_2, f$ are continuous.

I am doing this by taking the following limit:

$$\lim \limits_{(a,b) \to (x,y)} \int_{g_1(a)}^{g_2(a)} f(a, b) dy - \int_{g_1(x)}^{g_2(x)} f(x, y) dy$$

and showing that it $\to 0$.

My question is: for the first integral, should I replace $dy$ with a $db$? I think that I should but I'm not sure. Alternatively, is there a better way to express the limit so I don't run into this problem altogether?

Comment: $y$ is just a "dummy" variable of integration and the integral is a function of $x$ alone.  Therefore, the limit outside the integral is on $x$ only; there is no $y$.

Comment: @Dr.MV Oh, so to prove continuity i only have to have $a \to x$ and leave $y$ alone?

Comment: Yes, that is correct